# Avoid SQL`s JOIN when using ActiveRecord`s includes method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I've this ruby code which cause postgresql to raise `column "urls.id" must appear in the GROUP BY`.

```
Song.
  joins(:artist).
  references(:artist).
  where("artists.active = ?", true).
  group("songs.id").
  includes(:urls)
```

The problem is that rails is joining when adding `includes(:urls)` instead of running a separate query. Is it possible to force rails to run a second query to avoid this problem?

In other words; I want rails to use SQL's `JOIN` when using `ActiveRecord::Relation.joins` and a separate query when using `ActiveRecord::Relation.includes`.

Removing the `where` and the `references` method makes everything pass, but then I can't query against the artists table.

The error message.

```
SELECT "songs"."id" AS t0_r0, "songs"."artist_id" AS t0_r1, "songs"."title" AS t0_r2, "songs"."grade" AS t0_r3, "songs"."length" AS t0_r4, "songs"."gigs_count" AS t0_r5, "songs"."clicks" AS t0_r6, "songs"."album_cover_id" AS t0_r7, "songs"."created_at" AS t0_r8, "songs"."updated_at" AS t0_r9, "songs"."position" AS t0_r10, "songs"."services" AS t0_r11, "songs"."moved_id" AS t0_r12, "songs"."details_updated_at" AS t0_r13, "songs"."genres_updated_at" AS t0_r14, "urls"."id" AS t1_r0, "urls"."url" AS t1_r1, "urls"."service_id" AS t1_r2, "urls"."media_id" AS t1_r3, "urls"."media_type" AS t1_r4, "urls"."extra" AS t1_r5 FROM "songs" INNER JOIN "artists" ON "artists"."id" = "songs"."artist_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "url_bridges" ON "url_bridges"."media_bridge_id" = "songs"."id" AND "url_bridges"."media_bridge_type" = 'Song' LEFT OUTER JOIN "urls" ON "urls"."id" = "url_bridges"."url_id" WHERE (artists.active = 't') AND "songs"."id" IN (944) GROUP BY songs.id
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "urls.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ...AS t0_r13, "songs"."genres_updated_at" AS t0_r14, "urls"."id...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "songs"."id" AS t0_r0, "songs"."artist_id" AS t0_r1, "songs"."title" AS t0_r2, "songs"."grade" AS t0_r3, "songs"."length" AS t0_r4, "songs"."gigs_count" AS t0_r5, "songs"."clicks" AS t0_r6, "songs"."album_cover_id" AS t0_r7, "songs"."created_at" AS t0_r8, "songs"."updated_at" AS t0_r9, "songs"."position" AS t0_r10, "songs"."services" AS t0_r11, "songs"."moved_id" AS t0_r12, "songs"."details_updated_at" AS t0_r13, "songs"."genres_updated_at" AS t0_r14, "urls"."id" AS t1_r0, "urls"."url" AS t1_r1, "urls"."service_id" AS t1_r2, "urls"."media_id" AS t1_r3, "urls"."media_type" AS t1_r4, "urls"."extra" AS t1_r5 FROM "songs" INNER JOIN "artists" ON "artists"."id" = "songs"."artist_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "url_bridges" ON "url_bridges"."media_bridge_id" = "songs"."id" AND "url_bridges"."media_bridge_type" = 'Song' LEFT OUTER JOIN "urls" ON "urls"."id" = "url_bridges"."url_id" WHERE (artists.active = 't') AND "songs"."id" IN (944) GROUP BY songs.id
```

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.3.2 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc-4.4.real (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3, 64-bit.

Comment: Please show your PostgreSQL version (`select version()`) and the SQL generated by Rails, along with the actual error produced by PostgreSQL.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is it, that you want to achieve? If you use `group` you can't fetch the data of your models in the same request.

Comment: @phoet I want to force a second query when using `includes` to prevent the given error.

Comment: @phoet Look at the code like this instead `Song.complex_query.includes(:urls)`. I'm doing some kind of complex query against the songs table, but I also want rails to include all urls for each song. Instead of tampering with the query (doing a JOIN and adding all fields from the urls table into the SELECT clause) I want rails to do a second query.

Comment: So then just execute another query?! I still don't get it...

Comment: @phoet But I want the same behavior as the `includes` method, which in my case means that I want to be able to do `Song.scope.includes(:urls).each { |song| song.urls }`.

Comment: When you go for `group_by` things generally tend to get messy, have you considered explicit `select` and fetch just columns you need?

Comment: @bbozo I think you missed the point. I'm trying to make rails not to mess with my "complex" query. Ignore the #group and read my comment I wrote to phoet above. I spoke to some ppl at the rails irc and apparently the current behaviour of `includes` and `joins` isn't working correctly. The `references` method in rails 4 is a good start, but not 100% implemented yet.

Comment: Aaah, you want artists to join songs, but fetch the urls in a separate query?

Comment: Can you give more information on the relations between the entities? (artist has many songs probably, but what about urls?)

Comment: Song has many artists and urls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `includes` with `preload`, the documentation is not clear enough of it's internals but it will run a second query to eager load the relationship you specify. I've used it for your same use case with `joins` and `group`.

```
Song.
  joins(:artist).
  references(:artist).
  where("artists.active = ?", true).
  group("songs.id").
  preload(:urls)
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-preload

Comment: Yay, that works perfectly! I had no idea that method existed. Thanks! I'll accept your answer as soon as I've tested the preload method a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a second query for the urls manually. Don't use the includes(:urls).

```
@songs = Song.complex_query
@urls = Url.where(:song_id => @songs.ids)
@urls_by_song_id = @urls.group_by {|u| u.song_id}
```

Using group_by will put the urls into a hash with the key being the song_id and the value is an array of urls. You would access the urls like this:

```
@urls_by_song_id[song.id]
```

It isn't as clean as the includes, but it has the same effect. This gives you access to the urls without the n+1 overhead.

Comment: This is a workaround, but not a valid solution to my problem, sorry. It doesn't solve the problem of the `includes` method messing with my query.

Comment: Totally cool! I didn't know about preload so I got to learn something too!